# Are food calorie values really integers?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry, calorimetry

According to what I've seen, fat has a listed caloric value of 9 Cal/g, while carbs and protein have listed caloric values of 4 Cal/g.* Are these numbers exact, or have they been rounded? And if they have been rounded what are the exact numbers? One hit said that the numbers are rounded, but not by how much.

*These are "food calories" (aka "large calories" or "Calories" with a capital "C").
1 food calorie = 1000 "small calories" or "gram calories" = 1 kcal = 4.184 kJ

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calorie

Comment: I have burnt in my memory from deep past rather 4.3 kcal/g for "carbs" and 9.1 kcal/g for fats. So yourvalues are definitely rouded up, covering the value span across particular food components.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They're not exact numbers. These numbers aren't exact for three reasons:

1. Each type of carb, protein, and fat has a different caloric value.  These are overall averages for each class.
2. Even if you were dealing with a single pure compound, the value couldn't be exact because there is individual variation in how much of that compound is metabolized based on digestion, absorption, etc.
3. Even if #1 and #2 were not issues, the number still couldn't be exact, because it is a measured value, and measured values are never exact.  Only counted numbers, and values that are exact by defintion (e.g., the speed of light in SI units) are exact.

To get a better idea of how these values are determined, and the issues and uncertainties associated with measuring them, I'd recommend reading through:

Food and Agriculture Organization of the United Nations. *FAO food and nutrition paper*. Chapter 3:  Calculation of the energy content of foods - energy conversion factors. Food and Agriculture Organization of the United Nations, 1979.

Here is a direct link to chapter 3:

http://www.fao.org/3/Y5022E/y5022e04.htm

Comment: 1. Are you saying that, for example, saturated fat may have a different caloric value to unsaturated fat, and that refined carbs may have a different caloric value to complex carbs, etc?

Comment: Not only that, but a saturated triglyceride containing three 16:0 fatty acid chains will have a (slightly) different caloric value per gram than one containing, say, two 16:0 chains and one 14:0 chain.  And, likewise, different carbs will have different caloric values.  Whether such differences, particularly if they are small, are nutritionally significant, is an entirely different question.  But you weren't asking about nutritionally significant differences, you were asking if the numbers are exact.

Comment: Thx for you input. I edited the question heading, after realizing that it missed the mark slightly.

Comment: 3. What I am interested in is if the average between the different sub-classes of fat was rounded up, or down, to 9, and with how much?

Comment: I added a link that should help give you a picture of the situation.

Comment: @ToddMinehardt  Nope, I'm not off by a factor of 1000. First, it's understood from context that these are nutritional Calories (=1000 calories).  The OP's mistake was just in not capitalizing the "C". Second, I never specified either "calorie" or "Calorie" in my answer. Third, and most importantly, anyone who carefully thinks this through will see that your "gotcha" is what's immaterial since, logically, his questions—about whether these values are exact, and whether there are within-class differences between these values—are independent of how the unit itself is scaled.

Comment: My question is a follow-on to another question I recently posted on the Biology site. I would be very grateful if you could have a look at it and tell me what your thoughts are. Unfortunately the question is closed so one can not answer it, but a little thoughtful comment here or there would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Constantthin  The effects of low-fat vs low-carb diets is a very complicated and unresolved issue in the field of nutrition.  I took a quick look through the primary source (https://www.cell.com/cell-metabolism/fulltext/S1550-4131(15)00350-2) cited in the popular press article you linked and, IME, to the extent they are seeing differences it is not because they used an incorrect figure for the caloric value of fat.  If you read the primary source you can see there are many metabolic differences created by the different diets, and that's much more likely to be the explanation.

Comment: Whatever the explanation is for this phenomenon, would you agree that one ought to inflate the number of consumed fat-calories when counting calories to lose weight? Like with 10%-20%? Thus, should one make 1000 fat-calories to read 1100 or 1200?

Comment: @Constantthin: What's the point of counting calories if you're just going to make arbitrary adjustments? That's not counting, that's guessing badly on purpose.

Comment: @Constantthin  Simply put, no.  I don't know how many studies have been done on the effect of diet compositon on weight loss, but it's enormous—when I entered "diet composition and weight loss" in Google Scholar I got 2,520,000 results.  And their findings are all over the map.  So here you want to take the result from just *one* study and, based on this, adjust the current consenus figures for the caloric value of fats vs carbs. The problem is that you could probably find another study with the opposite result; so do you adjust these again, in the opposite direction, after reading that one?

Comment: I have just read through the original study-notes and concluded that although a low-fat diet leads to fat-loss, it doesn’t necessarily lead to weight-loss. Because on the opposite low-carb diet muscle-mass is lost, which leads to weight-loss. So there is a difference between fat-loss and weight-loss., apparently.

Comment: Yes. Now you're starting to see the some of the complexity.  Weight change is due to changes in fat, muscle, and water.  Anytime you use up carbs you temporarily lose a lot of weight, because while the body can store nearly pure fat, it can only store carbs as a combination of about 25% carbs and 75% water.  So a lot of weight loss at the start of a diet is loss of water due to loss of carbs. Conversely, with aerobic training, weight will increase (in a good way) because of increased blood volume. And with weight training, weight will  increase (in a good way) because of increased muscle mass.

Comment: This is completely out of the realm of chemistry, but the best advice I've heard is the best diet is the one that doesn't feel like a diet, i.e., the one on which you feel the best and the one that you can stick to.  If you've got that sorted, the particular dietary compositon is of secondary importance.

Comment: @theorist to be fair, this convention (Cal = 1000 cal) is absolutely horrible, and the interpretation of the order of magnitude shouldn't depend on the context. If the question is wrong, it should be edited, especially now that it's on HNQ. Finally, it does seem relevant to know if a value is ~4 or ~4000 when asking if it's an exact integer. The exact value could be 3998, as an example. Good answer, BTW, I'm only referring to the above comment.

Comment: @EricDuminil  (1) Agreed it should be edited; just did so.  (2) Agreed, one convention would be better.  But both are in such widespread use, there's nothing to be done.  E.g., to express everything as cal or J, you'd need to re-do every nutrition label in the US. And since they are in such widespread use, most are aware of both and can thus adjust based on context. (3) My comment was in reply to a comment by another poster, which he's since deleted (so you can't see the context), in which he insisted the fact that the scaling wasn't properly specified made both the question,and my answer,....

Comment: ... "immaterial".  That's not just unfair, it's false. That's why I replied as I did. (4) The choice of scaling really isn't relevant to the question of whether a number is exact.  That turns purely on the inherent nature of the value itself, and is entirely independent of the scaling factor used for the associated unit. All the integers you mentioned: (4, 4000, and 3998)—and, indeed, any integer value—could be either exact or inexact.....

Comment: ... Ask yourself this: Is there any way—any way at all—in which my answer would need to be different if the questioner expressed those values as cal instead Cal? [I.e., if he instead referenced 9000 cal/g for fats, and 4000 cal/g for carbs and proteins.] The answer is clearly no, demonstrating the compete irrelevance of the scaling factor to the question at hand. (5) Thanks for the positive comment on my answer :).

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't "take one calorie to burn", you *gain* one calorie by burning.

Now noting obviously what everybody else has said about selection of the type of fat affecting the precise amount of energy available from one gram (which in practice will be measured in a calorimeter), but what this is really saying is that by metabolising some specified fraction of a gram of fuel you can do (approximately) one calorie of work, e.g. raising the temperature of water by some specified amount or moving your muscles in such a way that they lift a weight by some specified number of centimeters.

So no, it's not an integer: it's an approximation to the amount of work you'd have to do to prevent the food you've just eaten being stored as flab, and to get an accurate figure you'd have to do an assay of an identical portion of that food taking into account both its chemical composition and its digestibility (e.g. an increased amount of fibre in the specimen might not change the result of the physical calorimetric test, but might change the availability of the nutrients to the digestive system).